# Firebase Google Sign In task doesn't run ContinueWith() method in Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, task, google-signin

I imported `FirebaseAuth.unitypackage` and `google-signin-plugin-0.1.4.unitypackage` into my project and wrote the following code as a signin manager:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Firebase.Auth;
using Google;
using UnityEngine;

public class GoogleSignInManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GoogleSignInManager Instance;
    public GoogleSignInManager() => Instance = this;

    private FirebaseAuth _auth;
    public FirebaseUser CurrentUser => _auth?.CurrentUser;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration = new GoogleSignInConfiguration
        {
            RequestIdToken = true,
            WebClientId = "xxxx"
        };
    }

    public Task<FirebaseUser> SignIn()
    {
        var signIn = GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn();
        var signInCompleted = new TaskCompletionSource<FirebaseUser>();
        signIn.ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            Debug.Log($"In signIn ContinueWith (status = {task.Status:g})");
            if (task.IsCanceled)
                signInCompleted.SetCanceled();
            else if (task.IsFaulted)
                signInCompleted.SetException(task.Exception ?? new Exception("Task Is Faulted"));
            else
            {
                var signInUser = task.Result;
                var credential = GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(signInUser.IdToken, null);
                _auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(authTask =>
                {
                    Debug.Log($"In SignInWithCredentialAsync ContinueWith (status = {authTask.Status:g})");
                    if (authTask.IsCanceled)
                        signInCompleted.SetCanceled();
                    else if (authTask.IsFaulted)
                        signInCompleted.SetException(authTask.Exception ?? new Exception("Task Is Faulted"));
                    else
                        signInCompleted.SetResult(authTask.Result);
                });
            }
        });
        return signInCompleted.Task;
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        _auth.SignOut();
        GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignOut();
    }
}
```

This works and shows the Google SignIn window in android, but the problem is that after I select my email it just closes and `Debug.Log($"In signIn ContinueWith (status = {task.Status:g})");` doesn't get called at all. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong as I get no errors and it just doesn't work.
I'm wondering what did I do wrong and how can I fix the issue.

**Update 1**

Added `signIn.Wait();` before `return signInCompleted.Task;` and now my application freezes as the task doesn't actually complete.

**Update 2**

As mentioned in the comments section, I checked the logcat and found that my `Debug.Log();` has executed in there and is not visible to the `IngameDebugConsole`. So the task completes and the `ContinueWith()` method actually runs. But now the problem is in the following code:

```
GoogleSignInManager.Instance.SignIn().ContinueWith(task =>
{
    if (task.IsCanceled)
        Debug.Log("Please Try Again!");
    else if (task.IsFaulted)
        Debug.LogError(task.Exception?.Message);
    else
    {
        var user = task.Result;
        Debug.Log(user.Email);
        email.text = user.Email;
    }
});
```

The `Debug.Log(user.Email);` or any other main thread method doesn't run. I want to show user's email address in a `UnityEngine.UI.Text` but it doesn't get called.

Comment: sanity check: did you build in release mode?

Comment: yes, I did @HarshdeepSingh

Comment: **Debug**.Log()

Comment: @HarshdeepSingh I used `IngameDebugConsole` package to see debugs at runtime, and I have tested without those lines too, no luck.

Comment: Try using logcat to see if the sign-in plugin logs any errors.

Comment: @MohammadZamanian please can you send me the all code with solution please? If yes, ask me for my email, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContinueWith` is not guaranteed to be executed on the Unity "main" thread.

Since you have the Firebase anyway specific for Unity rather use the `ContinueWithOnMainThread` from the [Firebase `TaskExtensions`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension)

```
GoogleSignInManager.Instance.SignIn().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
{
    if (task.IsCanceled)
        Debug.Log("Please Try Again!");
    else if (task.IsFaulted)
        Debug.LogError(task.Exception?.Message);
    else
    {
        var user = task.Result;
        Debug.Log(user.Email);
    }
});
```

Comment: The code you mentioned didn't work, but when I added a function in my calling class and called it where I used `Debug.Log(user.Email);`, It worked!