# C# Script for Fire Base DataBase Loop Not Logic

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I got this FireBase DataBase Query Script in Unity to return the line count in my JSON databse.

I don't understand the way it loops in and out of the script and would like to call function `CalledFunction()` after it finishes its loop but doesn't work... It always picks up the function while running. How come It reaches ''IN 4'' before it goes fully in the function and out??

Note that database is reached with my real private link disregard with the error in the log.

```
public void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("IN 0");
    // Get the root reference location of the database
    FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance("https://THISISMYDATABASEPRIVATELINK.com").GetReference("COUNT LIST").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.Log("ERROR IN FIREBASE LINK ACCESS");
        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            Debug.Log("IN 1");
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            string count = snapshot.ChildrenCount.ToString();
            Debug.Log("STRING COUNT : " + count);
            FireBaseData.intcount = System.Int32.Parse(count);
            Debug.Log("IN 2");
        }
        Debug.Log("IN 3");
    });

    Debug.Log("IN 4");
    CalledFunction();
}

public void CalledFunction()
{
    Debug.Log("This is Something Else");
}
```

This is my output LOG.

[LOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13cf3.png)

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your LOG output as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's requested here not to to use images for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Comment: But I think you need to await the task before calling `CalledFunction()`, e.g. with another `ContinueWith()` or by restructuring your `Start()` method to be `async` and awaiting it directly.

Comment: And if you need to continue on the main thread see [Firebase Google Sign In task doesn't run ContinueWith() method in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65646886/3744182).

Comment: For a general explainer on async tasks in Unity3d/Firebase see https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html

Answer (score 0):

as the name says `GetValueAsync` is executed async .. meaning in a different [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task) (similar to thread) and itself is a non-blocking call.

Thus, the lines

```
Debug.Log("IN 4");
CalledFunction();
```

are not delayed but immediately reached and executed.

---

If you want to wait with the `CalledFunction` call until you got the results of the database back what you would rather do is move your method call within the awaiter of the async Task.

For Unity specific make sure to not use `ContinueWith` but rather the extension method [`ContinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension#class_firebase_1_1_extensions_1_1_task_extension_1af1fc309e7e9b9e9a3655b8b47cb06014) which additionally makes sure that callback is executed in the Untiy main thread so you can use the Unity API without threading issues.

```
public void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("IN 0");
    // Get the root reference location of the database
    FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance("https://THISISMYDATABASEPRIVATELINK.com").GetReference("COUNT LIST").GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.Log("ERROR IN FIREBASE LINK ACCESS");
        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            Debug.Log("IN 1");
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            string count = snapshot.ChildrenCount.ToString();
            Debug.Log("STRING COUNT : " + count);
            FireBaseData.intcount = System.Int32.Parse(count);
            Debug.Log("IN 2");

            CalledFunction();
        }
    });
}

public void CalledFunction()
{
    Debug.Log("This is Something Else");
}
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but now Im missing something else ...

Assets\Scripts\FireBaseData.cs(27,113): error CS1061: 'DatabaseReference' does not contain a definition for 'ContinueWithInMainThread' and no accessible extension method 'ContinueWithInMainThread' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseReference' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Did you maybe forget the `GetValueAsync`?

Comment: I did, thats right, I also changed 
ContinueWithInMainThread to ContinueWithOnMainThread